# Error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in cakephp even thought the name of the model has been defined

Tags: php, function, oop, cakephp

Error: Call to a member function create() on a non-object in cakephp. I have already defined all of these in my controller page.

**ContactsController:**

```
<?php
 public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
 public $components = array('RequestHandler');
 public $uses = array("Contact");

 public function index(){
  if ($this->RequestHandler->isPost()) {
    $this->Contact->set($this->data);
    //validates here
  }
?>
```

**index.ctp**

```
<?php
//form
echo $form->create("Contact");
echo $form->inputs();
echo $form->end('Send');
?>
```

But am I still getting the fatal error. need help thanks.

Comment: lol, i totally forgot. it should be $this->Form->create("Contact");

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a very narrow, specific case and not applicable to the general public.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I disagree since that's valid syntax for version 1.3 and before. It changed in version 2.0

Answer (score 4):

Use `$this->Form->create()` instead of `$form->create()`.

You must use `$this` before helper object.

Your index.php code should looks like:

```
<?php
//form
echo $this->Form->create("Contact");
echo $this->Form->inputs();
echo $this->Form->end('Send');
?>
```

Comment: yeah, did that, i forgot for a bit. but why am i getting this error again?Call to a member function send() on a non-object. is this because I am using cakephp.2?

Comment: Check the book.cakephp.org how to work with the new CakeMail class in cake2 and the most important read the migration guide where all the changes are listed.

Answer (score 0):

Check your controller classes well. Did you redefine AppController::render() or reimplement it in a subclass? You might have done so to specify a layout for your application.
I was getting the same error. And I discovered that the $view argument(which is the name of the view to be rendered) that goes into the render method was null because I overrode the render method. 
If you didn't overrride render(), check for anywhere you might have set the $view property of the controller.